# Use Soapui 4.5.0 pro for REST testing without upgrading to 5x versions

Tags: rest, automation, soapui

I have been using Google Chrome's POSTMAN to test REST services. But now when its time to automate those test cases I learned that SOAPUI is best.

I have been given SOAPUI 4.5.0 to start with. I am new to SOAPUI. I searched for its "Getting Started" but Tutorials are there for 5x versions only.

Does Soapui 4.5.0 supports REST testing at all? If YES where is its "Getting Started"?

Answer (score 0):

Since SmartBear, the vendor for SoapUI, is a for-profit organization, they updated their tutorials for new released versions.

In 4.5, just use "New soapUI Project" and provide your WADL. Then you can continue with the rest of the steps in the [new tutorial](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html).

If you do not have a WADL, which is quite common, you will have to define all the methods manually. This is described in the [subsequent tutorials](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/rest-resources-and-methods.html).

Next time, if you are brand new to a tool, as you mentioned, it might be worth spending some time with the documentation first?